# ---MODIFIED--- VBA Word - Find "- " inside a word and left the word

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, find, wildcard

OLD
-----How could I do that? I've tried with this, but it crashes ant execute

```
Sub Sintesis()

            With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
                .Text = "([^$])" & "-^p" 
                .Replacement.Text = "\1" 
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


            End With
End sub
```

Some help? Before anyone tell me this, I prefer to do this with find/replace instead of Regex
END OLD-----

I've seen I was solving partially my real problem. What I really need is to remove the "- "string between the two halfs of a word. I can't replace "-" by "" because my text have some correct strings like the first one.

I actually need to conver this:
"Blablablab- labla"
Into:
"Blablablablabla"

Comment: Can you provide the text on which the `.find` is applied?

Comment: Why are you using `[^$]`? What do you expect to find?

Comment: What is your error on execute?

Comment: Sorry I forgot it. I'm trying to find splitted words within a OCRed document. 

For example, If I find a paragraph with : 
"blablablabl-  
ablabla."
I wnat this macro to repair it. Sometimes "-" is followed by linefeed,space+linefeed,space+paragraph


And error throwed is 5692

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with RegEx. Using the following recursive procedure

```
Sub ReplaceHyphens() ' Make sure you add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
    Dim rex As New RegExp
    rex.Pattern = "(.)-(.)"
    rex.Global = False
    Dim str As String: str = ActiveDocument.Content
    Dim mtch As Object
    If rex.Test(str) Then
        ActiveDocument.Content = rex.Replace(ActiveDocument.Content, rex.Execute(str)(0).SubMatches(0) & ActiveDocument.Content, rex.Execute(str)(0).SubMatches(1))
        ReplaceHyphens
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works OK, thank you, but I'd prefer to do it without regexp object.

Comment: You are welcome, I am sorry i am not familiar with Word's Find/Replace. So I am afraid I won't be able to help you much. Can I ask why you don't want to use RegEx?

Comment: Because as you with find/replace, I'm not familiar with regex and I'd like to understand what the hell I am doing XDDD. I'm a total newbie with vba macros

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**:

```
Sub FindDash()
With Selection.Find
                .Text = "([0-9A-z])- ([0-9A-z])"
                .Replacement.Text = "\1\2"
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
End Sub
```